# Replace one-line text with newline-separated texts

Tags: string, text, replace, find, notepad++

I have this string of 5,000 people

`532433.pptx John 22 AZ 432343.pptx marry 32 CZ 294838.pptx Sam 14 LA.....`

It is separated by xxxxxx.pptx

I want to convert to this:

```
 532433.pptx John 22 AZ 
 432343.pptx marry 32 CZ
 294838.pptx Sam 14 LA
 .....
```

Like Excel's Copy and changing row and column paste.

I managed to find that pattern number(xxxxxx.pptx) by Notepad++ Regex (^[0-9]+.pptx)

But how to import found query(532433.pptx) into replace field?

Comment: What is "Find and Plus"? Plus what?

Comment: You want to replace (^[0-9]+.pptx) with CR/LF + (^[0-9]+.pptx)?

Comment: Please, the next time try a bit harder to make your question undoubtful and work on typos before publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Find what: `([0-9]+.pptx)`

Replace with: `\r\n\1`

Regular expression mode

---

Input:

```
532433.pptx John 22 AZ 432343.pptx marry 32 CZ 294838.pptx Sam 14 LA
```

Output:

```
532433.pptx John 22 AZ 
432343.pptx marry 32 CZ 
294838.pptx Sam 14 LA
```

---

`\r\n` is newline, `\1` is the match corresponding to first bracket (`\2` would correspond to second etc. if there were more than 1 brackets in regexp).